# Can anybody suggest me,How to implement pause and resume functionality to this Data Receiving Code?

Tags: c, linux, http, sockets, download

This is Data Receiving functionality Code from http server, Perfectly Working.. But i want to add pause and Resume to this function..
can anybody suggest me how to do that ??
Note: Ignore variable Declaration.

```
int rest=0,size=0,count=0;                               
memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer));
do {
    rc=read(sockfd,buffer,1500);                  //Reading from socket connection
    if(rest==0)
    {   /*Extracting Content length*/
        data=strstr((char*)buffer,"Content-Length"); 
        if(data!=NULL)
        {
            value=atoi((char*)data+15);data_rest=value;
            rest=1;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
    {   /*Extracting Header*/
        content=strstr(buffer,"\r\n\r\n");
        if(content!=NULL)
        { 
            printf("FOUND Header END\n");
            content=content+4;count=1;
            /*copying DATA to the file which has same Extension*/
            data_wrote=fwrite(content,sizeof(char),rc-(content-buffer),fp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        content=buffer;
        /*copying DATA to the file which has same Extension*/
        data_wrote=fwrite(content,sizeof(char),rc,fp);
    }
    size=size+rc;
    total_wrote=total_wrote+data_wrote;
    printf("Total size = %d\n",size);

    memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer));
} while(rc>0);  /*until end of file*/
```

Comment: Pause and resume **where** and why do you need this sort of thing?

Comment: tcp buffer will handle that; why take extra burden on app?

Comment: it it my project.. To implement functionality of  "wget"

Comment: Do you mean that you want to *stop* the transfer, and then at a later time come back and *resume*, i.e. keep the sem-downloaded file and just ask the server for the remainder?

Comment: @unwind, Correct..we should able to pause downloading..and then again able to resume it..!!

Comment: @mojkaro1988, pausing a download is done by simply closing the connection. Then, when you wish to resume, you add a `byte-range` header to your new request, telling the server to skip (not send) the initial bytes you already have. (You might wish to keep some state in between, though -- at least the `Last-Modified`, `Content-Type`, and `Content-Length` response headers, and only resume the download if they still match. Otherwise the content might have changed from under you.)

Comment: @Nominal Animal,Thanks..I will try & reply you soon...

Comment: @Nominal Animal,sorry for late reply...by using byte range read call is sticking somewhere in between.. !!

Comment: read call is sticking? I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. For a byte-range response, `Content-Length` describes the length of the response, not the length of the original data. You need to look at the `Content-Range` response header (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) to see where in the original data the `206 Partial content` response belongs to, and how long the original content is.

Comment: @Nominal Animal,Can you help me with some pseudo Code ?

Comment: @mojkaro1988, pseudocode for which part? I wrote an answer roughly outlining the steps [but it is not an answer to your question, so please do not mark it accepted], and a Bash script you can use to explore the headers and content you should be able to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the process I would use:

- Send the initial request with `Range: bytes=0-` HTTP/1.1 request header.
  If the server responds with a `HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content`, you know you can resume the connection later.
  Save the `ETag` response header, as it should stay unmodified unless the content on the server changes, and/or the `Content-Type`, and `Last- Modified` headers.
  Note that the `Content-Range` response header specifies the offsets of the bytes in this response, with the final number being the total length of the full content, and `Content-Length` only specifies the length of the current response (not the length of the original content).
- Interrupt the transmission by simply closing the connection.
- Send the continuation request with `Range: bytes=N-` HTTP/1.1 request header, where `N` is the offset to the first byte still missing from the local copy.
  If the server does not respond with a `HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content`, you have no recourse but have to download the entire content again (using normal HTTP request processing).
  If the `ETag`, `Content-Type`, or `Last-Modified` response headers mismatch, then it is possible the content was modified on the server, and you should drop this connection and download the full request instead.
  The `Content-Range` response header specifies the offsets of the bytes in this response, with the final number being the total length of the full content, and `Content-Length` only specifies the length of the current response (not the length of the original content).

In all cases it is possible the server uses the `chunked` content transfer encoding, so you must be prepared to handle that, toom since the request is HTTP 1.1. See the [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for details.

When you test this, I recommend you use a simple Bash script to connect to some URL using your custom headers, and to output the response headers to standard error and message content to standard output:

```
#!/bin/bash

Host="localhost"   # Host name, use your own servers
Port="80"
Query="/"          # Path to the content requested
Range="0-"         # Byte range requested

# Open up a connection
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$Host/$Port || exit $?

# Set up a reader sub-shell that will flush the headers
# to standard error, and content to standard out.
(   Headers=1
    while read Line ; do
        Line="${Line//$'\r'/}"
        if [ -z "$Line" ]; then
            Headers=0
        elif [ $Headers -gt 0 ]; then
            printf '%s\n' "$Line" >&2
        else
            printf '%s\n' "$Line"
        fi
    done
    exit 0
) <&3 &

# Construct a byte-range request:
Request=""
Request="$Request""GET $Query HTTP/1.1"$'\r\n'
Request="$Request""Host: $Host"$'\r\n'
Request="$Request""Range: bytes=$Range"$'\r\n'
Request="$Request""Connection: close"$'\r\n'

# Do a normal request.
printf '%s\r\n' "$Request" >&3

# Close the connection (the read end is still open).
exec 3>&-

# and wait for the request to complete.
wait
```

The above is not a HTTP client, and does not do chunked transfers, for example; it is just a debugging tool you can use to see exactly the data that flows from the server to the client side.